# Numpy: finding the kth largest or smallest in 2D array between two sets

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I got a distance matrix between 5 places (name like [0,1,2,3,4]) which is 5 \times 5 2D array

```
f = np.array([[  0.        ,  67.72689426, 260.42493099, 228.21915948,
    234.46787035],
   [ 67.72689426,   0.        , 204.04482377, 165.98264605,
    166.7409761 ],
   [260.42493099, 204.04482377,   0.        ,  38.06217772,
     41.69615233],
   [228.21915948, 165.98264605,  38.06217772,   0.        ,
     11.32050776],
   [234.46787035, 166.7409761 ,  41.69615233,  11.32050776,
      0.        ]])
```

If we know that there are three sets, like,  {0}, {1,2}, {3,4} how can we find the kth largest or kth smallest value between sets.

For example, the max between sets {0} and {1,2} is 260.42493099.

Comment: does performance matter or space or code readability?

Comment: it doesnt matter

Comment: @NicolasH What you mean by kth largest or kth smallest value between sets? is largest value in both sets? or the largest value difference like 260.42493099 - 0.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fully vectorized solution based on NumPy's [`ix_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) and [`unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```py
def kth_extreme(arr, ind1, ind2, k=1, ascending=True):
    values = np.unique(arr[np.ix_(ind1, ind2)])
    return values[k-1] if ascending else values[-k]
```

Notes:

- To obtain the largest (or the smallest) value you have to use `k=1` (the default value) in the function call. For the second largest (or smallest) you have to pass in `k=2`, and so forth.
- There may be repeated values in selected subset of entries of the input array `arr`. The solution above considers the repeated values as a single value. If you wish to take multiple values into account you should change `np.unique(arr[np.ix_(ind1, ind2)])` to `np.sort(np.ravel(arr[np.ix_(ind1, ind2)]))`.

#### Demo

```py
In [1152]: f
Out[1152]: 
array([[  0.        ,  67.72689426, 260.42493099, 228.21915948, 234.46787035],
       [ 67.72689426,   0.        , 204.04482377, 165.98264605, 166.7409761 ],
       [260.42493099, 204.04482377,   0.        ,  38.06217772,  41.69615233],
       [228.21915948, 165.98264605,  38.06217772,   0.        ,  11.32050776],
       [234.46787035, 166.7409761 ,  41.69615233,  11.32050776,   0.        ]])

In [1153]: kth_extreme(f, [0], [1, 2], ascending=False) # largest
Out[1153]: 260.42493099

In [1154]: kth_extreme(f, [0], [1, 2]) # smallest
Out[1154]: 67.72689426

In [1155]: kth_extreme(f, [1, 2], [3, 4], k=2) # second smallest
Out[1155]: 41.69615233
```